# Java: Should I be logging issues in the event dispatch thread (EDT)?

Tags: java, event-dispatch-thread

I was wondering if it is acceptable to be writing to a log file directly in the event dispatch thread. I know a rule of thumb is to keep long operations out of the EDT, however I am unsure if a single write to a text file would fall into this category. I currently have worker threads doing this but I am running into some strange exceptions. Before researching these exceptions I thought I would see if it would be ok to just do these log writes directly in the EDT. As I said, these writes are relatively small and infrequent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your app keeps being responsive (and I guess it does), I don't see any reason why you wouldn't do it. Writing a line to a file is very fast: fast enough to be unnoticeable by a human eye.

Comment: @JBNizet I know it is really fast, I guess another thing I was worried about though was if the write were to fail, or if some other exception occurred, that it would start to lock up the GUI. If I am way off base here and there is nothing to worry about please let me know, that's why i asked. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: An exception thrown from the logger won't lock the GUI. It will bubble up the stack and make the current event listener method to fail, and then everything will continue working. Of course, it could leave your program in an inconsistent state, but it's not different from any other exception that could occur in the EDT. And the probability for a log method to throw an exception is very small. If you're really worried about that, you could enclose the log into a try/catch clause, but I would check that the logging framework doesn't do it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest dispatching this to [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). This will hand the actual file write off to a background thread. However, if you are using a framework such as log4j, you should investigate what buffering or other multithreading the library performs first.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you suggest this? In a comment above I was told it should be okay to do this in the EDT since it is such a quick operation. If you have any insight please elaborate, I would love to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: As said, it depends on how you're logging. If you're using a framework like Log4J it probably will make no difference. However as a general rule it's good to avoid potentially long-running IO on the event thread -- it may certainly make no difference, but if you are worried, it *cannot hurt* to hand off execution to a worker thread.